# Is it possible to delete documents in Apache CouchDB's temporary view?

Tags: couchdb

All documents in my database have a timestamp:

Example document:

```
{
    ...
    "timestamp": 1404587326,
    ...
}
```

With a map reduce I am able to filter all documents older than a certain date, for instance older than yesterday, but how can I delete those documents older than yesterday?

```
function(doc) {
    var yesterday = Date.now() - (60*60*24);
    if(doc.timestamp < yesterday) {
        delete(doc._id); // how??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all, your map reduce code does not work!**

Your map function is only called when a document is changing. So the `Date.now()` function will be the date at the time the map function was called the first time after a change to the document, not the actual time you access the index that is build by the function.

Also I was not aware that you can delete a document in a view.

**This is how you could achieve it**

Use the date as the ID in your map function, and return the Id of the documents. 
Then use your client app to call the view with the `startkey` parameter, which you can set to `Date.now() - 24*60*60`.

The view will then only return the documents that are more recent than the `startkey`, but not yet delete any documents.

Your map function will look something like:

```
function(doc){
  emit(doc.timestamp, doc);
}
```

**Do you really need to delete documents?**

If you really want documents that are older than 2 days to be deleted, you may not have the best database using couchdb. Couchbase - which is similar to couchdb in some ways and MongoDB both offer document expiry options as far as I know.

Alternatively you could access the documents with the above map function occasionally. But use the endkey, so that you retrieve all older documents. You'd then need to individually delete them.

**Finally temporary views**

I'm not sure why you want to use one of these, just store your view.

Comment: Interesting and clear answer, thanks. I wont really need to delete documents often, I would probably need this once or twice a year to shave off old documents (most certainly older than one day).

Comment: best not to `emit(..., doc)` -- this embeds a full copy of the document into the view, which in most cases is not needed for query performance, and in addtion duplicates what's already available in the db itself. A simple `emit(doc.timestamp)` would be sufficient here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the view approach that @dashservice as given, and then issue an HTTP DELETE /db/docname, or use the _bulk_docs API endpoint if you have many of them.

A common couchdb design pattern is to store documents into separate databases that can subsequently be dropped / deleted when those documents are not required.